# Regex to parse a config file, where the # sign represents a comment

Tags: regex

With the strings

```
Test=Hello World #Some more text
Test=Hello World
```

I need both to capture the "Test" group and the "Hello World" group. If the string starts with a "#" it should not be captured at all.

The below expressions work for the first and second strings, respectively:

```
^((?!#).+)(?:=)(.+[\S])(?:[\s]*[#])
^((?!#).+)(?:=)(.+[\S])
```

How do I do a bitwise logical OR between two non-capturing Regex groups?

I tried doing something like

```
^((?!#).+)(?:=)(.+[\S])(?:[\s]*[#])|(?:.*)
```

but can't get it to work out correctly.

**More Details**

Background: This is being done in C# (.NET Framework 4.0). A file is being read line by line. The text to the left of the equalize sign refers to a variable name and the text to the right of the equalize sign refers to the variable's value. This file is being used as a config file.

General cases:

Note: All trailing whitespace - any whitespace after the end of the last non-whitespace character should not be captured. This also includes any space between the end of the second group and the pound sign.

1) All characters, except for a whitespace, followed immediately by an equalize sign, followed immediately by any set of characters followed by a space and a pound sign. e.g.

```
this=is valid #text
s0_is=this #text
and=th.is #text
the=characters after the    # Pound sign are irrelevant
```

2) The exact same situation as case 1 except that there is no trailing space between the second capture group and the pound sign. e.g.

```
this=is valid#text
s0_is=this#text
and=th.is#text
the=characters after the# Pound sign are irrelevant
```

3) The same situation as in cases one and two; however, where there is no # sign at all (see the above note about trailing whitespace). e.g.

```
this=is valid
s0_is=this
and=th.is
the=characters after the
```

For all three of these cases the capture groups should be as shown below, respectively (the | symbol is used to distinguish between capture groups):

```
this|is valid
s0_is|this
and|th.is
the|characters after the
```

Special cases:

1) The first character of the line is a # sign. This should result in nothing being captured.

2) The # sign occurs immediately after the = sign. This should result in the second capture group being null.

3) The # sign occurs anywhere else not otherwise explicitly stated above. This should result in nothing being captured.

4) There should be no whitespace preceeding the first character of the new line; however, this case is unlikely to actually occur.

5) A space immediately after the equalize sign is invalid.

Invalid cases (where nothing should be captured):

```
th is=is not valid#text
nor =this#text
 or_this=something
also= this
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're making this more difficult than it needs to be.  Try this regex:

```
^(\w+)=([^\s#]+(?:[ \t]+[^\s#]+)+)
```

I used `[ \t]+` instead of `\s+` to prevent it from matching the newline and spilling over onto the next line--assuming the input really is multiline, of course.  You can still apply it to standalone strings if that's what you prefer.

**EDIT**: In answer to your comment, try this regex:

```
^(\w+)=(\w+(?:[ \t]+\w+)*)
```

With the first regex I was trying to avoid making confining assumptions and I got a little carried away. If you can use `\w+` for all words it becomes much easier, as you can see.

Comment: The actual purpose of this is to parse out a config file, where the `#` symbol is used as the comment character. Your solution works in some, but not all of the test cases. It works for the two strings that I posted as examples, but it does not work for `Test=Hello_World #Some more text` or for any case that does not have a space in the second capture group's portion.

I modified your solution to `^(\w+)=([^#]+(?:[^\s#]+)+)` and this seems to work as desired. Not sure if it is necessarily the most _correct_ version, but it does the job :) Thanks!

Comment: Try the regex I just added to my answer.

Comment: That one will not work if there is a period in the string such as in the string `Test=Hello.World #Some more text`. The second capture group will return "Hello". The first capture group must be everything before the "=" and the second capture group must be everything between either " #" or "#", with the latter used only for a string such as `Test=Hello World#Some more text`. The regex must also return nothing if the first character is "#".

Comment: Tell you what, why don't you give us a complete list of the characters you want to allow, so we can quit this guessing game.  And please add it it to the question, not in a comment.  Also, what regex flavor are you using?  That can make a big difference.

Comment: See the above edits. I believe this should cover everything. I also edited the title to something a bit more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
^((?!#).+)(?:=)(.+[\S])(?:[\s]*[#])|(?:.*)
```

means match

```
^((?!#).+)(?:=)(.+[\S])(?:[\s]*[#])
```

OR

```
(?:.*)
```

try this

```
^((?!#).+)(?:=)(.+[\S])(?:(?:[\s]*[#])|(?:.*))
```

although `(?:.*)` seems kind of pointless, why don't you try something like this instead:

```
^((?!#).+)(?:=)(.+?\S)(?:\s*[#])?
```

that will optionally match the last group, which is what I think you're trying to do, and it would be the better option in this case.

Comment: I agree that `(?:.*)` seems pointless, I just did not know how to represent that. I tried both of your solutions and they do not work for me. They include the `#Some more text` portion of the string with the `Hello World` group. I need it to not include the trailing space, pound sign, and everything following thereafter.

Comment: that has to do with the greedy behavior of (.+\S), try changing it to the lazy alternative, (.+?\S), that should do the trick

Comment: also, you don't need a character class for only one thing :S

Comment: That's getting closer, but now it's not greedy enough! It seems to stop after only 2 characters, i.e. the second capture group in my string example would only be `He` instead of `Hello World`

Comment: The closest thing I've come up with thus far is `^((?!#).+)(?:=)([^#]*)`;however, it leaves an additional space in the second capture group with the first string

Comment: put a greedy space after it to consume all of the unwanted space. `^((?!#).+)(?:=)([^#]*)\s*` I think that should work

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to make a difference :\

Comment: hmm, if there's always going to be a space, you could force the space to match by changing the last `\s*` to `\s+`, but that won' t match if there isn't a space there. you should always apply a second regex to the second capture group to remove any trailing spaces....

Comment: So this isn't perfect as it does not include a trailing space if there should be one; however, I think it will work for my purposes `^((?!#).+)(?:=)((?:[^#]*)[^ #])`. Thanks for the help!